# how to identify root cause of signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in my production Android application

Tags: android

My current production Android application has reports of the following Crash within the Google Play console

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.my.application <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000089fc4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #00  pc 000000000055b744  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2260)
  #00  pc 0000000000013990  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000012fb4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+320)
  #00  pc 0000000000276010  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::gc::accounting::SpaceBitmap<8ul>::VisitMarkedRange<art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::ImmuneSpaceScanObjVisitor const&>(unsigned long, unsigned long, art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::ImmuneSpaceScanObjVisitor const&) const+168)
  #00  pc 0000000000255e24  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::CopyingPhase()+1584)
  #00  pc 0000000000253968  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::RunPhases()+1048)
  #00  pc 00000000002773ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)+312)
  #00  pc 0000000000294044  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+4060)
  #00  pc 00000000002916ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::DoPendingCollectorTransition()+116)
  #00  pc 00000000002abf18  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectorTransitionTask::Run(art::Thread*)+36)
  #00  pc 00000000002e4bc4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+64)
  #00  pc 000000000001273c  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+124)
  #00  pc 0000000000059384  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal+196)
  #00  pc 0000000000024e80  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+160)
  #00  pc 000000000015d6f8  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a9a6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 0000000000553330  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460)
  #00  pc 00000000005a1ec8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1288)
  #00  pc 00000000000eb9ac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 000000000008c2bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

the stack trace provided does not mention any of my application packages

how can i identify the root cause of this issue?

currently this crash has only occurred once and it is not mentioned in my analytics reports from New Relic

Comment: I am looking for the same answer actually want to learn about all of the signal errors and root causes of these issues.